# Not able to connect USB or gamepad through Type-C adapter

Tags: usb, game-controllers

I'm trying to connect a gamepad with my mobile but it is not connecting.

1. On mobile 1 (Xiaomi Redmi), I connected the gamepad it was not working. I found that the gamepad works only with applications that request USB permission. So I installed an app that asks for USB permission, and it worked. I installed a game, cast the screen on the TV and everything was working fine. After a few seconds, it stopped working. And now it is not connecting anymore. Before connecting, I tried to read an SD card through a USB port and it was working fine. Now even that is not working.
2. On mobile 2 (another version of Xiaomi Redmi), it shows that the gamepad is connected as the light is not blinking but always on. But nothing works.
3. On mobile 3 (OnePlus), did a few attempts, but it didn't work. But then it started working automatically. Without giving any additional permission. Probably it was trying to download some driver in the background, no idea.

**Additional info**

1. USB tethering is disabled. It says the USB is not connected. But if I connect the data cable with a laptop then it's connected.

How can I debug or fix this issue on Xiaomi mobiles?

**Update**
It seems weird. But when mobile battery is less than 15% then it automatically connects.

Comment: What's the gamepad model? Does this happen for all gamepads or just one? Does it still time out with a Bluetooth-connected gamepad? Based on the description I'd guess this is a problem on the device's side.

Comment: It is happening with all devices like USB, microsd card through OTG, gamepad, c port headphones. Etc. Ideally OTG option should be developer option, I believe. But not in my case.